# InvalidArgumentException : You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available. Laravel Seeding

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a seed with Laravel 6 and the problem is that it generates the data on the product table when i try to connect with category_id and this error appear. Below is my code.
Migration File:

```html
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('categories_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

ProductSeeder:

```html
foreach (range(1,3) as $i) {
            Product::create([
                'user_id' => \App\User::all()->random()->id,
                'category_id' =>\App\Category::all()->random()->id,
                'name' => $faker->name,
                'active' => $faker->randomElement(['1', '0']),
                'description'=> $faker->sentence,
            ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don’t have the “active” column in the table, so you also need to remove it from the seeder